# How Ground wire triggers breaker?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

From the best of my understanding Ground wire are having less resistance than the live wire and when short circuit happens , current flow through ground wire , which allow  higher electricity flow than the live wire , that will switch the Breaker and cut the electric circuit to save from getting electric shock to human . I am quite new and couldn't understand how Breaker is triggered and please correct me if I get this concept wrong .

Comment: Breakers keep things from burning down. GFIs prevent humans dying.

Comment: @JonCuster That's true since breakers trip at currents many times higher than the current that can cause electric shock. But they do, in combination with grounding equipment metal housings, lower the voltage between the housing and  ground as well as limit the duration of any excess voltage to ground. These two factors reduce the risk of electric shock.

Comment: Are you asking about the machanism of how Breaker works?

Answer (score 1):

The principle equipment safeguard against electric shock is electrical insulation. The main supplemental safeguards against electric shock, should insulation fail, are GFCIs (ground fault circuit interrupters) and equipment grounding. You are talking about the equipment grounding safeguard, which I will briefly discuss below.

By connecting accessible metal of equipment to earth ground by the ground wire, if there is an insulation failure between a “live” conductor and the metal housing, including a short-circuit, there is a low impedance current path to ground keeping the metal close to ground potential (depending on the impedance). This reduces the voltage a person would experience if touching the metal with, say, the hand with some other part of the body touching a grounded surface.

Now electric shock depends on many factors, but two of them are (1) the amount of current through the body and (2) how long  (in time) the current flows through the body. The circuit breaker, being typically 15 A does not help with (1) since lethal electric shock is on the order of 20 to 100 mA (that’s the job of GFCIs which trip at nominally 5 mA). But the breaker does limit the time of the fault event by tripping.

The tripping of the circuit breaker is a function of the combination of the overcurrent and time. The greater the overcurrent to ground during the fault, the faster the breaker operates, and the lower the exposure to the shock current. So a low impedance grounding conductor, which allows more current to flow, makes the breaker trip more quickly.

This explanation is necessarily simplified as books have been written on the subject.

That said, hope this helps.